# How to mute/unmute remote video/audio in twilio

Tags: reactjs, twilio

I found that this can be used:

// Disable playback of a remote audio track
remoteAudioTrack.enablePlayback(false);

but how to use it, I mean how will i access remoteAudioTrack class

Answer (score 0):

```
    const toggleVoice = () => {                                // Voice toggle event handler
       if (voiceStatus === "Mute") {
           room.localParticipant.audioTracks.forEach(audioTrack => {
               audioTrack.track.disable();
           });
           setVoiceStatus("Unmute");
       } else {
           room.localParticipant.audioTracks.forEach(audioTrack => {
               audioTrack.track.enable();
           });
           setVoiceStatus("Mute");
       }
   }

   const toggleVideo = () => {                                 // Video toggle event handler
       if (videoStatus === "Stop Video") {
           room.localParticipant.videoTracks.forEach(videoTrack => {
               videoTrack.track.disable();
           });
           setVideoStatus("Start Video");
       } else {
           room.localParticipant.videoTracks.forEach(videoTrack => {
               videoTrack.track.enable();
           });
           setVideoStatus("Stop Video");
       }
   }
```